# Neon instruction, vsub_f32(a, b), is it a-b or b-a?

Tags: c++, arm, neon, intrinsics

In this neon instruction (from [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/BABIBDGG.html)):

```
float32x2_t vsub_f32(float32x2_t a, float32x2_t b);  // VSUB.F32 d0,d0,d0
```

Does it return a - b or b - a? I cannot find it in the ARM documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the expanded documentation for the Neon Intrinsics more useful. It also gives the mapping from functions parameters to instruction operands, and is available from:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0073a/IHI0073A_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf

For `vsub_f32`, that document gives the following:

```
float32x2_t vsub_f32 (float32x2_t a, float32x2_t b)
a → Vn.2S b → Vm.2S
FSUB Vd.2S,Vn.2S,Vm.2S
```

Answer (score 3):

> The VSUB instruction subtracts the value in the second operand
>   register from the value in the first operand register, and places the
>   result in the destination register.

from http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Bcffigdj.html

So, it´s `a-b`

Comment: Are the operands always in the same order for the c intrinsics as for the assembly intrinsics then?

Comment: @JanRüegg In theory, it´s not guaranteed, but anything else would be really stupid design.